# Bug moving on number line in random directions

Tags: probability, combinatorics, ordinary-differential-equations, probability-theory, expected-value

A bug at the origin moves on the number line either left or right $u$ units every second, where $u$ is am arbitrary real between -1 and 1. For example, the bug could go from 0 to -0.4 in one second, then -0.4 to 0.3 in the next second, etc.. How long (in seconds) do you expect the bug to take before it is more than or at least a distance 1 from the origin (i.e. its position is less than or equal -1 or greater than equal to 1)?

**EDIT #1**: I tried representing the expected value as a function of the position it is currently at, but couldn't get any further

**EDIT #2**: I ran a [computer simulation](https://pastebin.com/PcrfziMp) for about 100 million trials and got an answer of around $5.36457$, similar to @DreiCleaner .

@Mike Earnest had a promising approach expanding on my **[EDIT #1]**.

His appraoch:

Let $f(x)$ be the expected value of remaining steps if you are currently at position $x$. Then it can be shown that $f(x)=1+\frac12\int_{\max(x-1,-1)}^{\min(x+1,1)} f(t)\,dt$.

I do not see why this is true yet.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think as the bug has an equal chance to move in the opposite direction from the last movement, then it may take infinitely many seconds. Unless you make the interval, for example, $-2$ to $3$, that is a different chance of move left or right.

Comment: @Masacroso edited the OP, sorry

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve it exactly but for what it's worth I ran a few thousand simulations (just using Excel) and it appears the answer is around 5.3 or 5.4. Hopefully someone can provide what you're looking for.

Comment: If you let $f(x)$ be the expected number of additional steps it takes for the process to end when it is currently at $x$ (so you want $f(0)$), then you can show $f(x)=1+\frac12\int_{\max(x-1,-1)}^{\min(x+1,1)} f(t)\,dt$, which should give a differential equation $f$ satisfies and let you solve for $f$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I don't quite understand how you got the first equation, mind elaborating?

Comment: @theo01r It is basically the law of total expectation; if you are currently at x, then then next value is between x-1 and x+1, with equal probability to any region between. The total number of steps is 1 + the number of steps from the new location. We use $\max(x-1,-1)$ and $\min(1,x+1)$ to account for the boundaries. However, I have been trying to solve this differential equation (which you can get by differentiating both sides, and using symmetry), but I cannot figure it out...

Answer (score 2):

OK, here is what I have so far; I think this leads to a solution, but there is just some messy algebra near the end that I cannot bring myself to attempt.

As I mentioned in my comment, and you stated in your post, letting $f(x)$ be the expected number of steps starting, then for $x>0$, we have
$$
f(x)=1+\frac12\int_{x-1}^1f(t)\,dt\tag{1}
$$
Differentiating both sides with respect to $x$, you get
$$
f'(x)=-\frac12f(x-1)=-\frac12 f(1-x)\tag2
$$
where the last step follows since $f$ is an even function. Differentiating $(2)$ again, you get $f''(x)=\frac12f'(1-x)$, which combined with $(2)$ shows that
$$
f''(x)=-\frac14 f(x),\qquad 0<x<1\tag3
$$
Now, $(3)$ implies that
$$
f(x)=A\cos(x/2)+B\sin(x/2),\qquad 0<x<1
$$
for some constants $A$ and $B$. Note that this expression is only valid on the positive half of the domain, $0<x<1$. To extend this to the entire domain, you would use the fact that $f$ is even to write
$$
f(x)=A\cos(x/2)+B\sin (|x|/2)\tag 4
$$
All that remains is to determine the constants $A$ and $B$. This should be doable by substituting $(4)$ into $(1)$.

Answer (score 2):

I think Mike Earnest has already made a great answer, so I'll just finish up the tedious bits of finding the constants $A$ and $B$ of their answer, and I'll use their notation. I just plug in $f(x) = A\cos(x/2) + B\sin(|x|/2)$ into the integral equation
$$
f(x) = 1+\frac12 \int_{\max\{x-1, -1\}}^{\min\{x+1, 1\}} f(t) dt
$$
with my two favourite values of $x\in[-1,1]$, as long as they're not $\pm$ the same value because of the symmetry. Let's do $x=0$ and $x=1$ (or rather, we can take the limit as $x\to 1^-$). This gives the equations
$$
A = 1 + 2 A \sin(1/2) - 2B\cos(1/2) + 2B
$$
$$
A\cos(1/2) + B\sin(1/2) = 1 + B + A\sin(1/2) - B\cos(1/2)
$$
which are just linear equations in $A$ and $B$. The solution is:
$$
A = \frac{\sin(\frac12) - \cos(\frac12) + 1}{\sin(\frac12) + 3\cos(\frac12) - 3}
= 1 + \frac{4}{\cot(\frac14) - 3}
\approx 5.365299791
$$
$$
B = \frac{-\sin(\frac12) - \cos(\frac12) + 1}{\sin(\frac12) + 3\cos(\frac12) - 3}
= -1 - \frac{2}{\cot(\frac14) - 3}
\approx -3.182649895
$$
In particular,
$$
f(0) = A \approx 5.365300
$$
which matches the simulations :-)

For completion, below is the graph of $f$. I note the non-smoothness at the origin. Also the limit at $x\to \pm1$ might be of interest; it turns out to be
$$
A\cos(1/2) + B\sin(1/2) = 1+ \frac{2}{\cot(\frac14) - 3} \approx 3.182649894
$$
which apparently is just $-B$! I'm sure that makes sense somehow.

[image: f graph]

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I will award you the bounty when I can.