# Equilibrium in a tug-of-war game: What's the error in my solution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

I spent the last couple of hours solving [this problem](https://www.janestreet.com/puzzles/robot-tug-of-war-index/). I got a very good approximation of the solution, but not the actual solution, and I'm trying to understand why. I will show as succintly as I can how I conceived the problem and what I did. I will skip all calculations because I'm confident they are correct, and believe this is a matter of conception rather than of computation. Here's what I did.

---

Firstly, observe that the whole of the events in which Robot 1 wins are

\begin{align*}
    (R_1 wins)_1 &\cup \Big( (\neg R_1 wins)_1 \cap (\neg R_2 wins_1) \cap (R_1
    wins)_2 \Big) \\ 
                 &\cup \Big( (\neg R_1 wins)_1 \cap (\neg R_2 wins_1) \cap (\neg
                 R_1 wins)_2 \cap (\neg R_2 wins)_2 \cap (R_1 wins)_3\Big) \\ 
                 &\cup \ldots
.\end{align*}

where the subindex $i$ in $(R_k wins)_i$ and $(\neg R_k wins)_i$ means the event
of winning or losing occurred on the $i$th rope pull by the robot $k$. So in
natural terms we have that either $R_1$ wins on the first pull, or $R_2$ does
not win on
his own first pull and $R_2$ wins on his second pull, or $R_2$ does not win on
his first and second pull and $R_1$ wins on his third pull, and so on.

Let $p_0$ be the initial position of whatever marker the robots have to pull beyond $0.5$ or $-0.5$ to win. We are asked to find the $p_0$ that gives equal chances to both robots.

$i$. The probability $(R_1 wins)_1$ is simply $\frac{1}{2} + p_0$.

$ii.$ The probability of not winning the first pull is $(\frac{1}{2} - p_0)$. The expected value of the marker in that case is $p_0 + \frac{1}{2}$, so

$iii$. the
probability that $(\neg R_2 wins)_1$ is $1 + p_0$, and the expected value at
this point is for the marker to be back at $p_0$, so

$iv$. the probability $(R_1
wins)_2$ once more $\frac{1}{2} + p_0$.

Computing the probabilities in this way, we always have the same expected value for the marker's position after the robots do not pull a win. To be very clear (since I believe my error is here), I conceive that after $R_1$ fails to pull a win, the expected position is $p_0 + 0.5$. If then $R_2$ fails to pull a win, the expected position is once more $p_0$, and so on.

Thus, I arrived at the objective function

\begin{align*}
    f(p_0) = \left(\frac{1}{2} + p_0 \right) &+ \left(\frac{1}{2}-p_0\right)\left(1+p_0 \right) \left(\frac{1}{2}+p_0 \right) \\ 
            &+ \left(\frac{1}{2}-p_0 \right) \left(1+p_0 \right)\left(\frac{1}{2}-p_0 \right) \left(1+p_0 \right) \left(\frac{1}{2}+p_0 \right)
            \\ 
            &\ldots 
.\end{align*}

This comes down to

\begin{align*}
    f(p_0) = \left(\frac{1}{2}+p_0 \right) \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2} -
    p_0 \right)^i(1+p_0)^i
.\end{align*}

The series is a geometric series and converges within the interval of interest [-1, 1], so we reduce it to its closed form expression:

\begin{align*}
    f(p_0) &= \frac{\frac{1}{2} + p_0}{1- \left(\frac{1}{2}-p_0 \right)(1+p_0)} \\ 
           &= \frac{2 + 2p_0}{2p_0^2 + p_0 + 1}
.\end{align*}

Now, there are two ways to conceive the equilibrium point. One is to solve $f(p_0) =
\frac{1}{2}$, finding the value of $p_0$ that makes the chances equal. The
second is to solve for $f(p_0) = 1 - f(p_0)$, finding the $p_0$ that makes the
winning chances equal for both robots. The results for both approaches is the
same. Namely,

\begin{align*}
    p_0 = \frac{3 - \sqrt{17}}{4} = -0.28077\ldots
.\end{align*}

I was sad to observe that this is not the correct solution. However, it
approximates it extremely well. The correct answer is $p_0 = -0.28500\ldots$.

---

My solution is "correct" up to two decimal points, which I'm happy with. But I
am determined to understand my mistake. My guess is that the problem lies in the
fact that my objective function $f(p_0)$ does not conceive the position of the
marker after each failed pull using probabilities (that would require
convolutions and it gets messy). Instead, it just uses the *expected* position
of the marker, which is always $p_0$ after $R_2$ does not win, and is always
$p_0 + \frac{1}{2}$ after $R_1$ does not win. Perhaps this makes $f$ to only
approximate the actual solution? I'm a bit lost, and would appreciate any kind
of help.

Comment: I think my mistake might be that after $R_1$ fails to pull, the expected position is not $p_0 + 0.5$ (that might be a win, depending on $p_0$. I think it should be $p_0 + \frac{0.5 - P_0}{2}$, this is, the middle point between $p_0$ and $0.5$. Will update on this and am happy to hear thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first mistake is when you calculate $P(\text{$R_2$ does not win in round $2$)}$. You need to account for the fact that the probability that $R_2$ does not win depends on how much  $R_1$ moved the rope.

If $R_1$ does not win in the first round, it means $R_1$ brought the marker to some number $x$ between $p_0$ and $\tfrac12$. To find the probability that $R_2$ does not win in the second round, we "add up" the probability that $R_1$ moves to $x$, times the probability that $R_2$ does not win conditional on moving to $x$, for each $x$ in this interval. There are infinitely many $x$, so instead of summation, we need to integrate. The probability that $R_2$ does not win starting from $x$ is $(\frac12+x)$, so the total probability is
$$
\begin{align}
P(\text{$R_2$ does not win in round $2$})
&=\int_{p_0}^{1/2}(\tfrac12+x)\,dx
\\&=\tfrac12(\tfrac12+(\tfrac12)^2)-\tfrac12(p_0+p_0^2)
\\&=\tfrac38-\tfrac12p_0-\tfrac12p_0^2.
\end{align}
$$

The formula is more involved than you thought. If you try to extend the same reasoning to the probability of $R_1$ winning in the third round, and so on, you will get messier and messier integrals, so I think that this is not a viable method of attack.

---

Define a function $f(x)$ on the domain $[-\tfrac12,\tfrac12]$ as follows: $f(x)$ is the probability that the first robot will eventually win the game when the marker starts over $x$. For example, $f(\tfrac12)=1$. The goal is to find $x$ such that $f(x)=\frac12$.

We then use the law of total probability to get an equation for $f(x)$ in terms of itself. The probability the first robot wins on the first turn is $\frac12+x$. Otherwise, the first robot will push the number to some number $y$ in the range $[x,\frac12]$. Here is the trick that makes this problem tractable. At this point, it is $R_2$'s turn, starting from $y$. The probability that $R_2$ wins starting from $1$ is exactly the probability that $R_1$ wins starting from $-y$, which is $f(-y)$. You then subtract from one probability that $R_2$ wins to get the probability $R_1$ wins. Therefore, the function to be integrated is
$$
1-f(-y).
$$
Therefore, we get this equation for $f$:
$$
f(x)=(\tfrac12+x)+\int_{x}^{1/2}(1-f(-y))\,dy=1-\int_{x}^{1/2}f(-y)\,dy\tag1
$$
Taking the derivative of both sides with respect to $x$,
$$
f'(x)=f(-x)
$$
To solve this differential equation, note that
$$
f''(x)=[f'(x)]'=[f(-x)]'=-f'(-x)=-f\big(-(-x)\big)=-f(x)
$$
The differential equation $f''(x)=-f(x)$ implies that $f(x)=A\sin x+B\cos x$ for real constants $A$ and $B$. To find those constants, substitute the formula $A\sin x+B\cos x$ for $f(x)$ in $(1)$. I have not completed this problem, but I am pretty sure this method will work, since I have seen it used to solve a [similar problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3866128/).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145183/discussion-on-answer-by-mike-earnest-equilibrium-in-a-tug-of-war-game-whats-th); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.